# PagerTabStrip - center the tabs, or make them fit

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using this library https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip to create a PagerTabStrip.

My output [image]

You can see that after my tabs I have some empty space.
I want to make the tabs fit all the screen, or at least center the tabs.
Is that possible?

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/facebook_theme_light"
        android:id="@+id/activity_posts_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:background="@color/facebook_theme_dark"
        android:id="@+id/activity_posts_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/activity_posts_tabs"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Went looking for a solution for this, and there is one already built into the library, just use:

```
psts:pstsShouldExpand="true"
```

and the tabs will expand and center in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but it looked crazy when I tried to put it in comment form so here you go:

If you go to [the sample xml for the library you provided](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/res/layout/fragment_quick_contact.xml)

you will find that the xml has the view -

```
 <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tabs_diagonal"
    app:pstsDividerColor="#00000000"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FF33B5E6"
    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FF33B5E6" />
```

This has a width of `"match_parent"`. What you need to do in your app is change your equivalent of this to `"wrap_content"` and add `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`.... or something along those lines since I haven't tested it.

**EDIT**

You could also try wrapping it in a container

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs_diagonal"
        app:pstsDividerColor="#00000000"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FF33B5E6"
        app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FF33B5E6" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since i'm using a relative layout, I did wrap content, and         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 for my pagertabstrip. The result is this http://i.snag.gy/MHjEK.jpg... is centered, but i need to make it fit inside the layout..without thoose gaps at the sides and also, is possible to make them like equal to fit?

Comment: @Paul so you want them to span evenly across the whole layout? You will likely have to provide a custom view that handles measuring things out for you, but I will look into things when I get a minute and see if there isn't an option the help you out.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want http://i.snag.gy/svulG.jpg . I hope is possible to do with this library

Comment: @Paul According to that link, if you go into your library and modify the PagerSlidingTabStrip class, look for a similar line (making a guess it is 229 in the method addTextTab(), you can add the line that link tells you to add, rebuild your app, and you should be good

Comment: @Paul this is the git link to that file, https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java (again you are looking at the method addTextTab() after line 229... I think).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't edit from the Android Studio , because is complied code :D, and i'm too lazy to download the code, and use as a project library , i see that google solution is nice, just 3 classes and I'm done :) (is working now)

Comment: @Paul yea Google has a good slider library, I'd recommend it unless you have a reason to use the library you posted.